# many checkbox list not save in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, checkbox

i do some code to save data and i do code for checkboxlist to save it in data it's work with only one checkbox when i choose two checkbox it's just save the first one

like this

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dguA9.png)

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtOUz.png)

asp.net code

```
<table style="height: 172px; margin-top: 15px;margin-top:10px;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="auto-style5" style="padding-left:250px; font-size:29px"><strong>Faculty Members</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="width: 171px; font-size:20px">Frist Name:
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_fname" runat="server" style="width: 171px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="width: 108px; font-size:20px; padding-left:20px;">Last Name:
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_lname" runat="server" style="width: 171px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="height: 34px; width: 171px; font-size:20px">Specialization:
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="height: 34px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="width: 171px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="height: 34px; width: 108px; font-size:20px; padding-left:20px;">Degee:
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="height: 34px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_degree" runat="server" style="width: 171px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="width: 171px; font-size:20px">Addrss:
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_address" runat="server" style="width: 171px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="width: 128px; font-size:20px; padding-left:20px;">PhoneNumber:
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_phone" runat="server" style="width: 171px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="width: 171px; font-size:20px">Subject_ID:
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>DataBases</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Programming 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>programming 2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="width: 291px; font-size:20px">Faculty Members Number:
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Snumber" runat="server" style="width: 171px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2"  class="auto-style4" style="width: 108px; padding-left:50px">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>][1]
```

c# code

```
public partial class admins : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-677TN4G\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=homework;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Staff values('" + txt_fname.Text + "','" + txt_lname.Text + "','" + txt_Snumber.Text + "','" + txt_degree.Text + "','" + txt_address.Text + "','" + txt_phone.Text + "','" + CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue + "','" + txt_Snumber.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Data is Saved";
        txt_Snumber.Text = "";
        txt_fname.Text = "";
        txt_lname.Text = "";
        txt_address.Text = "";
        txt_degree.Text = "";
        txt_phone.Text = "";
        txt_Snumber.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: You're vulnerable to SQL injection with the way your code is currently written. Use parameterised queries.

Comment: You'll want to iterate over `CheckBoxList1.Items` and check the `Selected` property on each item. You also need to think about how you're going to store these in the database. You don't want three same exact rows with different subject names in that table; so you need to either store the selected values as a comma-separated string (gross) or create another table that holds a list of `id`s and `subject_id`s, with a composite primary key on both (aka a junction table)

Comment: i want it store the selected values as a comma-separated

Comment: Look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41840820/296861). You can just replace like  `txt_phone.Text + "','" + subjects  + "','" +`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join selected checkboxes' text.

*For example,*

```
string subjects = string.Join(",", CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(item => item.Selected)
    .Select(item => item.Text)
    .ToList());
```

***FYI***: You want to consider using parameterized query to prevent SQL Injection attack.